# How do house plants affect the quality of air in a house?

Tags: botany

Do house plants affect the air in the house by taking it from the rooms and it is put in the dirt to make it moist then we have no air.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

Plants have pores called *stomata*, where they generally intake CO<sub>2</sub> from the air. There's a transport system in the plant called the *phloem* which pulls organic compounds down into the roots. When you have pollutants in the air that get sucked into the plant through the stomata, they get sent down to the roots. There are hopefully microbes down in the soil, and the harmful compounds get expelled into the soil, and broken down by the microbes. All the while, the plant is expelling oxygen. This should, in theory, improve the air quality.

Comment: I've often wondered, is this *enough* of a change to say that they "affect" the air quality. As in, "how many plants does it take to get a measurable difference?"

Comment: That's something to look into, I don't know the answer myself. In fact, the answer to OP was just an elementary plant structure-function overview.

Comment: In my oppinion you corrected and answered the question neatly. I was simply musing. Perhaps it's worth a new question.